# How to Animate (slide) content adjacent to content with jquery toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am setting up a page which the user can hide the side bar if they wish. I am trying to use the jqeuryui to do this with the following js code

```
// TOGGLE JS
$(function () {      
    function runEffect() {           
        var options = {};            
        $("#effect").toggle('slide', options, 500);
    };
    $("#button").click(function () {
        runEffect();
        return false;
    });
});
```

I have this working in a JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jwg4U/

However, when you look at the JSFiddle you will notice that my main content area which is a DIV called `#content` does not animate, it just jumps into place when I toggle the sidebar.

I would like the content div to also slide into place seamlessly and follow the toggle as it if it attached to it.

I have looked at jquery animate, but not sure how to implement this with the slide?

---

A Second part I am struggling with is how to change the button text when the sidebar is closed to say "Show Sidebar" - Weather it is open or closed right now it just says "Hide Sidebar"

Looking for some help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jwg4U/23/

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="width:800px">

<div id="header">
     <h1>HEADER</h1>
</div>

<div class="toggler">
<div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:300px;width:100px;float:left;">
        <h3>SIDEBAR</h3>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:300px;">Main Content goes     here</div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Hide Sidebar</a>

<div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;">
FOOTER</div>

</div>
```

​

JS:

```
// TOGGLE JS
$(function() {
var i = 0;

function runEffect() {
    var options = {};
    if (i === 0) {
        i = 1;
        $(".toggler").animate({
            left: -100
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
    }
    else {
        i = 0;
        $(".toggler").animate({
            left: 0
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
    }
}
$("#button").click(function() {
    if (i === 0) {
        $(this).html("Show Sidebar");
    }
    else {
        $(this).html("Hide Sidebar");
    }
    runEffect();
    return false;
});
});

// TABS JS
$(function() {
$("#tabs").tabs();
});​
```

CSS:

```
 .toggler {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#button {
    padding: .5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#effect {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
#content{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
}
#button{
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
#header{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}​
```

Comment: (SCRATCH THIS, sorry does work, my bad pasting) I should probably note that the edit you made above does not work for me, weird...http://jsfiddle.net/jwg4U/23/ but this one does work http://jsfiddle.net/jwg4U/20/ the only line I can see u have changed is `if (i === 0) {` for some reason when I run it on my dev site nothing happens...strange

Answer (score 0):

The jsfiddle for the complete answer : http://jsfiddle.net/jwg4U/22/

```
  $('#effect').animate({
   width: 'toggle',
   height: 'toggle'
    }, {
   duration: 500,
   specialEasing: {
     width: 'linear',
     height: 'linear'
   },
   complete: function() {
      $("#content").animate(
           { left: '+=100px' },
           60, 
           'easeInQuad', 
           function () 
           { 
               if(isOpen)
               {
                  isOpen=false;  
                  $("#button").html('Show Sidebar');                     
                }
                else
                {
                  isOpen=true;
                  $("#button").html('Hide Sidebar');     
                }
             });
        }
   });
```